# Sampling numerical arrays in java

Tags: java, statistics

I have a data set of time series data I would like to display on a line graph. The data is currently stored in an oracle table and the data is sampled at 1 point / second. The question is how do I plot the data over a 6 month period of time? Is there a way to down sample the data once it has been returned from oracle (this can be done in various charts, but I don't want to move the data over the network)? For example, if a query returns 10K points, how can I down sample this to 1K points and still have the line graph and keep the visual characteristics (peaks/valley)of the 10K points?

I looked at apache commons but without know exactly what the statistical name for this is I'm a bit at a loss.

The data I am sampling is indeed time series data such as page hits.

Comment: I will suggest you to read the following paper "M4: A VisualizationOriented
Time Series Data Aggregation" it may give you some alternatives, It describes a method for losseles (in terms of presented visuallization) data-point reduction. This is done while you are retrieving the data with an sql query.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is to segment the 10K data points into 1K buckets -- the value of each one of these buckets may be any statistic computation that makes sense for your data (sorry, without actual context it's hard to say) For example, if you want to spot the trend of the data, you might want to use Median Percentile to summarize the 10 points in each bucket. Apache Commons Math have helper functions for that.  Then, with the 1K downsampled datapoints, you can plot the chart.

For example, if I have 10K data points of page load times, I might map that to 1K data points by doing a median on every 10 points -- that will tell me the most common load time within the range -- and point that. Or, maybe I can use Max to find the maximum load time in the period.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options: you can do as @Adrian Pang suggests and use time bins, which means you have bins and hard boundaries between them. This is perfectly fine, and it's called downsampling if you're working with a time series.

You can also use a smooth bin definition by applying a sliding window average/function convolution to points. This will give you a time series at the same sampling rate as your original, but much smoother. Prominent examples are the sliding window average (mean/median  of all points in the window, equally weighted average) and Gaussian convolution (weighted average where the weights come from a Gaussian density curve).

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to average the values over shorter time intervals. Make the length of the shorter interval dependent on the overall time range. If the overall time range is short enough, just display the raw data. E.g.:

- overall = 1 year: let subinterval = 1 day
- overall = 1 month: let subinterval = 1 hour
- overall = 1 day: let subinterval = 1 minute
- overall = 1 hour: no averaging, just use raw data

You will have to make some choices about where to shift from one subinterval to another, e.g., for overall = 5 months, is subinterval = 1 day or 1 hour?

My advice is to make a simple scheme so that it is easy for others to comprehend. Remember that the purpose of the plot is to help someone else (not you) understand the data. A simple averaging scheme will help get you to that goal.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is reduce the points of your visuallization without losing any visuall information, I suggest to use the code [here](https://github.com/drcrane/downsample). The tricky part of this approach is to find the correct threshold. Where threshold is the amount of data point you target to have after the downsampling. The less the threshold the more visual information you lose. However from 10K to 1K, is feasible, since I have tried it with a similar amount of data.

As a side note you should have in mind

- The quality of your visualization depends one the amount of points and the size (in pixels) of your charts. Meaning that for bigger charts you need more data.
- Any further analysis many not return the corrected results if it is applied at the downsampled data. Or at least I haven't seen anyone prooving the opposite.